# Where can I find a Swift 2.6.0 package?

Tags: server, apt, package-management, openstack, cloud

I'm facing [this Swift bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/swift/+bug/1503152), which is fixed in the 2.6.0 release of Swift, on Ubuntu 14.04 server.

I'm looking for a deb package of swift object server in version 2.6.0. As far as I know, cloud-archive (Ubuntu Server Team) provides version 2.5.0.

Alternatively, is there a way to securely apply the patch (probably [this piece of code](https://review.openstack.org/gitweb?p=openstack/swift.git;a=commitdiff;h=d01cd425094c2e56e4e89dbf3eaf887815dd5b62)) in a production environment ? I have not found any documentation in how to apply fix manually.

Comment: Adding a patch to a debian package has some documentation here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpdatingADeb Of course this will not get you the newest version but it would certainly add the patch you have linked to. Is this any help?

Comment: Thanks, but `apt-get source swift` tells there is no source package for swift. I was wondering if I could modify python code, directly in installed package (the `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swift/obj/replicator.py` file in my case), even if it sounds ugly.

Comment: Seems odd, I tested under Wily (Desktop not Server) and it works well enough: http://pastebin.com/zy1gdpRh Make sure you have 'Sources' checked in Software Updates (presuming you have a gui on your server...)

Comment: Ok, thank you ; indeed, I have an Ubuntu Server and sources retrieval is probably disabled by default.

Comment: You should be able to open /etc/apt/sources.list with your favourite text editor and remove the comment: '#' mark in front of lines marked deb-src. Then run 'sudo apt-get update'....

Comment: OK I have made this set of comments into a full answer as well as tested the syntax extensively. I hope that this will solve your issue. Let me know of any difficulties in my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download it, here:

http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/swift/swift_2.6.0-1_all.deb

Or here:

http://ftp.dk.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/swift/swift_2.6.0-1_all.deb

Comment: Do you know the kind of differences between these packages and those that will be provided by the Ubuntu Server Team ?

Comment: @MrJo there usually isn't one, as Ubuntu pulls most of its packages from debian. Packages get the ubuntu distro name on them after they are tested and released by the Ubuntu devs. There could potentially be differences, but it mostly has to do with dependency resolution and the fact that Ubuntu won't through it in the repository without ensuring that dependencies for this version of Swift are all available on your version of Ubuntu. You could install and and try it or download a portable version in a tarball to safely try it out before installing a package for it.

Comment: OK, thank you ; more widely, I'm asking some questions about versions compatibility in swift too, as aked [here](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/88410/versions-compatibility-matrix-for-swift/).

Answer (score 1):

The [Ubuntu Cloud Archive](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive) generally tracks the versions which shipped with each OpenStack release.  The latest OpenStack release (Liberty) shipped with swift 2.5.0, which is what is in the cloud archive.

The swift project's [series and milestone](https://launchpad.net/swift/+series) information, as well as the the [projected OpenStack Mitaka release summary](http://releases.openstack.org/mitaka/index.html) may be helpful to track.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different servers hosting the debian package for Swift.

[Germany Mirror](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/swift/swift_2.6.0-1_all.deb)
[Denmark Mirror](http://ftp.dk.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/swift/swift_2.6.0-1_all.deb)

There shouldn't be a whole lot of difference, but it's possible that they have the bug figured out.  The way to find out is to install and try it.  If the bug is still there then you know it's not fixed